# Are there USB-A to USB-C adapters for the Early 2015 MacBook

Tags: macos, hardware, usb

Apple announced a new 12" MacBook. The only port other than a headphone jack is USB-C. Since it is new technology I do not have any USB-C memory sticks.

What adapters will let older USB sticks work with this port and Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer - yes.

Apple has also announced an USB-C to USB connector for £15 in the UK store or $19 in the US store.

- [USB-C to USB (UK Store)](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter)
- [USB-C to USB (US Store)](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter)

It too isn't shipping yet, so it's hard to know if this is a custom chip and design or any old "connect the wires" adapter will do the trick. However, my guess is that it's just a simple adapter and there's no licensing like the lightning port requires/allows.

The specifications are that the port is just USB 3.1 Gen 1 which means that pretty much any USB-A device in existance will interoperate with the new MacBook.

Comment: Forgive the large edit. I'll undelete my answer if you're not comfortable with the amount of change I introduced.

Comment: @bmike - no worries at all. Both are/were correct at the time of writing ;) I see no reason to not keep it up to date & canonical.